# How to pass in my meat, rice and beans value, from my Burrito class to the meat class, rice class, and beans class respectively?

Tags: python, class

I have four classes, I am trying to pass in my meat value, rice value and beans value to their respective classes, and return their value through the `Burrito` class. I have battled with this for two days but no visible progress, any idea on what to do, apologies for any grammatical error. Below is the first three classes, According to the instructions given am not suppose to touch any line in the first three classes, all my code modifications should be in the `Burrito` class.

```
class Meat:
    def __init__(self, value=False):
        self.set_value(value)

    def get_value(self):
        return self.value

    def set_value(self, value):
        if value in ["chicken", "pork", "steak", "tofu"]:
            self.value = value
        else:
            self.value = False

class Rice:
    def __init__(self, value=False):
        self.set_value(value)

    def get_value(self):
        return self.value

    def set_value(self, value):
        if value in ["brown", "white"]:
            self.value = value
        else:
            self.value = False

class Beans:
    def __init__(self, value=False):
        self.set_value(value)

    def get_value(self):
        return self.value

    def set_value(self, value):
        if value in ["black", "pinto"]:
            self.value = value
        else:
            self.value = False
```

Here is the class were am suppose to pass in value from and return value from as well.

```
class Burrito:
    def __init__ (self, meat, to_go, rice, beans):
        self.meat = Meat(meat)
        self.set_to_go(to_go)
        self.rice = Rice(rice)
        self.beans = Beans(beans)

    def set_meat(self, meat):
        self.set_value(meat)

    def set_to_go(self, to_go):
        to_go_list = [True, False]
        if to_go in to_go_list:
            self.to_go = to_go
        else:
            self.to_go = False

    def set_rice(self, rice):
        self.set_value(rice)

    def set_beans(self, beans):
        self.set_value(beans)

    def get_meat(self):
        self.meat_v = Meat()
        return self.meat_v.value

    def get_to_go(self):
        return self.to_go

    def get_rice(self):
        self.rice_v = Rice()
        return self.rice_v.value

    def get_beans(self):
        self.beans_v = Beans()
        return self.beans_v.value
```

Here is the line am using to test my code:

```
newburrito = Burrito("pork", True, "brown", "pinto")
print (newburrito.meat)
```

This is the error line am getting:

```
<__main__.Meat object at 0x7fa5ad8bccf8>
```

Am expecting it to print

```
pork
```

Comment: You can simply do `newburrito.meat.get_value()` to access individual class values. I am not seeing any error there. You have just printed out `newburrito.meat` (which will return object).

Comment: Call your `get_meat` as `newburrito.get_meat()`

Comment: my print (newburrito.meat) is suppose to print pork

Answer (score 1):

First, your are not getting an error. You called print on the object meat and that is what happened, the print show that the object is of the class `Meat` and it also show the address of this instance in memory.

If you want to print the value stored on the attribute `value` inside the `Meat` class instance, you have to do `print(newburrito.meat.get_value())`, as it was already pointed in the comments.

Answer (score 0):

This exercise is about Python properties. If you are expecting `newburrito.meat` to return `"pork"` this means that `meat` is a *property* of the class `Burrito`, not a *method*, nor a *class instance*, which is how your code defines it.

Step 1. Make the class members *meat*, *to go*, *beans* and *rice* private. The convention is to start the name with an underscore:

```
class Burrito:
    def __init__ (self, meat, to_go, rice, beans):
        self._meat = Meat(meat)
        self._to_go = to_go
        self._rice = Rice(rice)
        self._beans = Beans(beans)
```

Step 2: Define *properties* to return *meat*, *to go*, *beans* and *rice*. For this you need a getter method (with decorator `@property`) and a setter method (with decorator `@xxxxx.setter`). The property definitions go *inside* the `Burrito` class: be sure to get the indentation right.

```
class Burrito:

    # ... continued ...

    @property
    def meat(self):
        return self._meat.get_value()
    @meat.setter
    def meat(self,value):
        self._meat.set_value(value)

    @property
    def to_go(self):
        return self._to_go
    @to_go.setter
    def to_go(self,value):
        self._to_go  = isinstance(value,bool) and value

    @property
    def rice(self):
        return self._rice.get_value()
    @rice.setter
    def rice(self,value):
        self._rice.set_value(value)

    @property
    def beans(self):
        return self._beans.get_value()
    @beans.setter
    def beans(self, value):
        self._beans.set_value(value)
```

Then you can use the properties `.meat`, `.rice` etc as though they were instance variables of `Burrito`, but instead, when you use them as r-values, the interpreter calls the getter method, and when you use them as l-values, the interpreter calls the setter method.

You can see how that works like this:

```
newburrito = Burrito("pork", True, "brown", "pinto")
print (newburrito.meat)
print (newburrito.rice)
print (newburrito.beans)
print (newburrito.to_go)

newburrito.meat = 'tofu'
print (newburrito.meat)
```

Output is

```
pork
brown
pinto
True
tofu
```

Answer (score 0):

Thanks everyone for the effort i appreciate all the pointers i got from your codes. @BoarGules thanks for pointing me to a whole new idea in python as am a beginner. I will research further into python properties and see what arsenal it adds to my tool kit for future challenges. I ended up writing the working code by drawing inspiration from everyone here. First of all the first three classes which is not meant to be touched:

```
class Meat:
    def __init__(self, value=False):
        self.set_value(value)

    def get_value(self):
        return self.value

    def set_value(self, value):
        if value in ["chicken", "pork", "steak", "tofu"]:
            self.value = value
        else:
            self.value = False

class Rice:
    def __init__(self, value=False):
        self.set_value(value)

    def get_value(self):
        return self.value

    def set_value(self, value):
        if value in ["brown", "white"]:
            self.value = value
        else:
            self.value = False

class Beans:
    def __init__(self, value=False):
        self.set_value(value)

    def get_value(self):
        return self.value

    def set_value(self, value):
        if value in ["black", "pinto"]:
            self.value = value
        else:
            self.value = False
```

My working Burrito class:

```
class Burrito:
    def __init__ (self, meat, to_go, rice, beans, extra_meat = False, guacamole = False, cheese = False, pico = False, corn = False):
        self.meat = Meat(meat)
        self.set_to_go(to_go)
        self.rice = Rice(rice)
        self.beans = Beans(beans)
        self.set_extra_meat(extra_meat)
        self.set_guacamole(guacamole)
        self.set_cheese(cheese)
        self.set_pico(pico)
        self.set_corn(corn)
    def set_meat(self, meat):
        self.meat.set_value(meat)
    def set_to_go(self, to_go):
        to_go_list = [True, False]
        if to_go in to_go_list:
            self.to_go = to_go
        else:
            self.to_go = False
    def set_rice(self, rice):
        self.rice.set_value(rice)
    def set_beans(self, beans):
        self.beans.set_value(beans)
    def set_extra_meat(self, extra_meat):
        extra_meat_list = [True, False]
        if extra_meat in extra_meat_list:
            self.extra_meat = extra_meat
        else:
            self.extra_meat = False
    def set_guacamole(self, guacamole):
        guacamole_list = [True, False]
        if guacamole in guacamole_list:
            self.guacamole = guacamole
        else:
            self.guacamole = False
    def set_cheese(self, cheese):
        cheese_list = [True, False]
        if cheese in cheese_list:
            self.cheese = cheese
        else:
            self.cheese = False
    def set_pico(self, pico):
        pico_list = [True, False]
        if pico in pico_list:
            self.pico = pico
        else:
            self.pico = False
    def set_corn(self, corn):
        corn_list = [True, False]
        if corn in corn_list:
            self.corn = corn
        else:
            self.corn = False

    def get_cost(self):
        cost = 5
        if self.meat.get_value() == "chicken" or self.meat.get_value() == "pork" or self.meat.get_value() == "tofu":
            cost += 1
        if self.meat.get_value() == "steak":
            cost += 1.50
        if self.extra_meat == True and not self.meat.get_value() == False:
            cost += 1
        if self.guacamole == True:
            cost += 0.75
        return cost

    def get_meat(self):
        return self.meat.get_value()

    def get_to_go(self):
        return self.to_go

    def get_rice(self):
        return self.rice.get_value()

    def get_beans(self):
        return self.beans.get_value()

    def get_extra_meat(self):
        return self.extra_meat

    def get_guacamole(self):
        return self.guacamole

    def get_cheese(self):
        return self.cheese

    def get_pico(self):
        return self.pico

    def get_corn(self):
        return self.corn
```

To get the meat, rice and beans instance of the Burrito class to communicate with the three classes above, I need to call their class getters and setters into the Burrito class getters and setters. Example to send a meat instance from Burrito class to Meat class i simply write my setter for the meat method in Burrito like this:

```
def set_meat(self, meat):
        self.meat.set_value(meat)
```

As seen in Burrito class above. Same applies to beans and rice.

Now to call values back from them, i simply call their respective class getters into my Burrito class getters. Example using the meat once more:

```
def get_meat(self):
        return self.meat.get_value()
```

Same applies to the rice and the beans class as seen in the Burrito class above:

For  the curious minds, this is a little way of testing it :

```
newburrito = Burrito("pork", True, "brown", "pinto", True, True)
print (newburrito.meat.get_value())
```

Thanks once more and apologies for any grammatical error. I hope my explanations were clear enough.
Note please i decided to post my entire code for clarity as against the select code i posted when i was asking my question.